# How can I create dict from extracting data of a .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm setting up an algorithm which get the values from a txt file into lists.

For example, the txt file can be:

```py
points
 -1 -4
 5 6
 7 8
NextPoints 1
points;
points
 -2 -7
NextFile 1
```

For now, I have created a dict:

```
number_of_points = text.count('points\n')
for i in range(number_of_points):
   dict=['list%s' % i] = list_points
```

The fact is that this dict returns:

```
{list1 : [-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8], list2 : [-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -2, -7]}
```

but I want this:

```
{list1 : [-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8], list2 : [-2, -7]}
```

The objective is to take in consideration all the 'points' in a file and to put each of them into a list. The major part on my text file contains only 1 'points' apparition.

**Update**

```
while line:
  if line.lstrip().startswith('points') and not (line.rstrip().endswith(';')):
     if line.startswith(' '):
         pointsDefect['list{}'.format(c)] = next(f).strip().split()
         c += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
result = {}
c = 1
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "points":    #If line == "points" Get data from next line.
            line = next(infile)
            temp = []
            while not line.strip().startswith("Next"):
                temp.extend(line.strip().split())
                line = next(infile)
            result['list{}'.format(c)] = list(map(int, temp))
            c += 1
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'list1': [-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'list2': [-2, -7]}
```

Comment: It returns: `{'list4' : ['NextPoints', '1']}`. It doesn't take in consideration the points. I've updated my question to explain more clearly what I've tried.

Comment: You have modified the input file?

Comment: No, it is the same, but the first one was not enough detailed.

Comment: Updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler solutions, why not something like this:

```
import re

result, current = [], []
with open("/path/to/file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if current and line[:6] == "points":
            result.append(current)
            current = []
        if re.match(r"(-?\d+ ?)+", line.strip()):
            current.extend([int(s) for s in line.split()])
result.append(current)

print(result)  # >> [[-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [-2, -7]]

# if you really need the {list1': xxx} pattern:
result = {f'list{i+1}': l for i, l in enumerate(result)}

print(result) # >> {'list1': [-1, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'list2': [-2, -7]}
```